# Перевод даты из числа в строку

Tags: bash, дата, shell

Добрый день! 
Имеется переменная date `date=$(date -d 2018-03-27 +%s)`, которая имеет значение 1522101600. Можно ли конвертировать это значение в строку "2018-03-27"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ date -d @1522101600 +%Y-%m-%d
2018-03-27
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ string=`date -d @1522242926  '+%d-%m-%Y'`
$ echo $string
28-03-2018
```

Comment: На `string=$(date -r 1522242926 '+%d-%m-%Y')`
выдаёт ошибку `date: 1522242926: No such file or directory`

Comment: `date -r 1522242926 '+%d-%m-%Y'` тоже самое